# XMLHttpRequest not sending POST data

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, post

I trying to send POST data to PHP file using XMLHttpRequest. The URL is right but PHP can't catch any of sent data and just back a null response.

I'm using pure javascript from client and PHP 7.1 on server

My PHP:

```
$data->msg = 'PHP is working';
$data->user = $_POST['user'];
$data->pass = $_POST['pass'];
echo json_encode($data);
```

My Javascript:

```
var data = { 'user': 'myUser', 'pass': 'myPass' };

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'myurl', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var res = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        console.log(res);
    }
};
xhr.send(data);

// Expected output: {msg: "PHP is working", user: myUser, pass: myPass}

// But just recive: {msg: "PHP is working", user: null, pass: null}
```

I expect this response: {msg: "PHP is working", user: myUser, pass: myPass}
But just recive this: {msg: "PHP is working", user: null, pass: null}

As you can see PHP $_POST can't catch my sent post data and just back null. What's worng??

Comment: what is data is being passed on your network console?

Comment: i would suggest to use "axios" for ajax requests, its better then vanilla javascript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is in your Content-Type. If you use `application/json` the PHP won't parse the post data into $_POST variable. You have to send them as form data to have PHP parse it.

See this question for more info [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest)

Alternatively you can use `file_get_contents("php://input")` to get the raw body of HTTP request and parse the json with `json_decode`.

**Example with file_get_contents and json_decode**

PHP Code:

```
$in = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded = json_decode($in, true);
$data = new stdClass();
$data->msg = 'PHP is working';
$data->user = $decoded['user'];
$data->pass = $decoded['pass'];
echo json_encode($data);
```

JS Code:

```
var data = { 'user': 'myUser', 'pass': 'myPass' };

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'myUrl', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var res = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
            console.log(res);
        }
    };

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    return false;
```

Please notice that you need to `JSON.stringify` the data object before passing it as argument to `send()` method. Otherwise the data are not send correctly.

Comment: Hi Michal, i'm trying with file_get_contents("php://input") but still output is null. Seems PHP doesn't catch anything...

Comment: I've added an example code for the `file_get_contents` approach that works for me. You also need to transform the data into string with `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Hi Michal, just one more question. Why with $.post (jquery) is possible send POST data to PHP but no with XMLHttpRequest json?

Comment: It's because of how the data are sent to server. JQuery's $.post is sending data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of json and that's why php parses the recieved data into `$_POST` variable. You can also send request with `XMLHTtpRequest` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and you will be able to find the data in `$_POST`. See the question i've linked in my answer to see how to do that.

Comment: Thanks Michael! Now with this explanation i understand the page you've linked. :)

Answer (score 4):

To receive json in php you need to read request body:

```php
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$data->msg = 'PHP is working';
$data->user = $request['user'];
$data->pass = $request['pass'];

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Hi, i don't understand. Why $request ? I've try with your code but nothing

Comment: `$request` is just a variable. I thought since you're receiving a request, `$request` name is right. btw do you see any data being sent in your network console?