# What request should I use instead of GET to send request with params?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, parameters, request

I searched the questions but there are answers everywhere to send parameters in the URL. In my case it will not work, because I have to send an array with a large number of elements and other params in the request. Because of this, I don't want to put it on the URL, just send it as request parameters. Is this correct? What query should I use instead of get? Please help me.

Comment: Try a `POST` request: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396101/pure-javascript-send-post-data-without-a-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading about the [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods#:%7E:text=The%20POST%20method%20is%20used,side%20effects%20on%20the%20server.&text=The%20PUT%20method%20replaces%20all,resource%20with%20the%20request%20payload.&text=The%20DELETE%20method%20deletes%20the%20specified%20resource.) method, which is used to "submit an entity to the specified resource, often causing a change in state or side effects on the server"

Comment: So you don't advise using a POST method?

Comment: No, you should absolutely use POST.

Comment: I do actually, if you're trying to send data to a server then you should use either POST or PUT (GET is for retrieving data), I personally have no experience with the latter. But you can read about the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-put-in-http).