# How i can send ajax request in Django with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: python, django

I want to send 'GET' and 'POST' requests using ajax in Django.  I looked few articles but they all were using jquery, I don't know how to use jquery so is there any way I can send 'GET' and 'POST' requests by using plain JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396101/pure-javascript-send-post-data-without-a-form

Answer (score 0):

You can use **XMLHttpRequest** Object of vanilla JS

For Get Request

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "ajaxfile.php?request=1", true);
xhttp.send();
```

For Post Request

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "ajaxfile.php", true); 
var PostData = {name:'yogesh',salary: 35000,email: 'yogesh@makitweb.com'};
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(postData));
```