# Making a post request and after submitting a form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, urlhelper

I am having this problem while working on an eshop I am building, I want to simply do a post request to a controller (that is not returning a view) while also submiting a form.. I do not know what is wrong with this code

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("sad");     
 $("a[data-form-method='post']").click(function (event) {

                event.preventDefault();

                var element = $(this);
                var action = element.attr("href");
                element.closest("form").each(function () {
                    var form = $("#form1");
                    form.attr("action", action);
                    form.submit();
                });
            });

        });
</script>
```

Here is the form

```
 using (Html.BeginForm("SendEmailToAdmin", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
                {
                    @Html.Hidden("receiver", $"{user.Email}");

                   
                    <a href="@Url.Action("AdminSupport", "Home",new { receiver = user.Email })" data-form-method="post">Customer Support</a>
                }
```

Here is the controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/Home/SendEmailToAdmin")]
        //[NonAction]
        public JsonResult SendEmailToAdmin()
        {
........
(some code
if is true )


      return Json(new { status = "Thank you very much admin for showing up. Don't forget to send us the email of your feedback on your way out" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

(or else)
            return Json(new { status = "Something went wrong, please try again" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I have tried also using a button with the id of submitDemo

```
  $('body').on('click', function (e) {
               e.preventDefault();
                    alert("Handler for .click() called.");

                   $.post("~/Home/SendEmailToAdmin");
            });
```

and also

```
            $("#form1").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.post('@Url.Action("SendEmailToAdmin", "Home",new { id = email })');

                document.signupform.submit();

            });
```

have also tried using a variable for the button and then with onclick method and so on...

```
  const button = document.getElementById('submitDemo');
```

EDIT : I HAVE TRIED THIS

Comment: What happens? Can you see any requests in your browser's developer console? Any javascript error messages? "doesn't work" does not count as a valid error description ;-) You may want to take a look e.g. here (2. answer, fetch API https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396101/pure-javascript-send-post-data-without-a-form) that describe how to send requests from JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply. No error whatsoever unfortunately....

Comment: It submits the form that is redirecting to the page.. That is the result actually

Comment: I can see a form and a controller that should accept the form. I cannot see code for any other request. So "it submits the form" seems to be expected behavior? If you expect any other additional request, which line of code should trigger this request? (and did you read the linked question on how to send HTTP requests from JavaScript?)

Comment: @ChristophLütjen  At this version I have it now. The Href is supposed to target the controller sending the email.name data also submiting the form and yes i have just started reading it. Thank you very much again

Comment: @ChristophLütjen this one -- > <a href="@Url.Action("AdminSupport", "Home",new { receiver = user.Email })" data-form-method="post">Customer Support</a>

Answer (score 1):

I fount it at last.. here it goes!
Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#submitBtn").click(function (event) {
    console.log("sad");
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "@Url.Action("SendEmailToAdmin", "Home")",
      data: "@email",
      success: function () {
        console.log("Done")
        $("#form1").submit();
      }
    });  
  });
});
```

html in view : I added the `btn` outside of the form
and this way the submit form happens and also the post request!

```
using (Html.BeginForm("AdminSupport", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
{
  @Html.Hidden("receiver", $"{user.Email}");

  @*<button id="submitbutton" @user.Email=>Customer Support</button>*@
}
<button id="submitBtn" @*data-form-method="post"*@>Customer Support</button>
```